# What is this way of declaring a JavaScript function inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I am studying a codebase, and I see an object where some methods are declared this way:

```
Object.assign( className.prototype, {
    method: function () {
        // some var declarations and initializations
        return function method(params) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Why declaring methods this way? Is it because the code before the "return" gets somehow executed only when the object is declared and the returned function when the method is called?

Comment: No, thats just old syntax for writting `class className { method() { /*...*/ } }`

Comment: I don't refer to the object structure, but to the inside part

Comment: Are you sure the examples you've found are using `Object.assign()` and not `Object.create()`?

Comment: Your speculation is not accurate, the method is simply a function that returns another function and this has nothing to do with how the method is declared.

Comment: `Is it because the code before the "return" gets somehow executed only when the object is declared and the returned function when the method is called?` it's not executed somehow, except if you call `yourObject.method()`. This call initialize the closure and returns another function that you'll call whenever you want, and it will obviously use the variables from the closure!

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code example that shows how "some var declarations and initializations" and "do stuff" are related?

Comment: @sjahan except the codebase uses such methods by calling them from the object

Comment: @Todd Chaffee I can't go much more specific as it's not open source code